# Layout not pushed up when Soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

I have a fragment of this given layout hierarchy,

[image]

Inside the view pager I have a Edit text. When keyboard appears to type in the text to EditText the entire layout is not pushed up. Instead the contents inside ViewPager is pushed up. I want the entire content inside the Outer Linear Layout to be pushed up when keyboard appears.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which `windowSoftInputMode` have you set on your activity?  See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> will try and move the entire layout up instead of re-sizing it.

Comment: Hi this worked for me .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put your Parent LinearLayout inside a scrollview. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

put your base layout inside the *ScrollView*

```
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPlayersName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >
        // do here the layout work
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

remember scrollView cannon be used as the base layout, so you have to put the scrollView inside the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's manifest entry, add

```
<activity ...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```